# FormType : required attribute doesn't work with Entity Type

Tags: symfony, validation, symfony-3.4

I'm working with Symfony 3.4, and when trying to add required HTML5 attribute to my "fournisseur" Field, I didn't get it in HTML.

## ArrivageType.php:

```
$builder
->add('fournisseur', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Fournisseur',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    //'empty_data'  => null,
    'required' => true,
))
```

Comment: by default required is true. please show all corresponding code.

Comment: Was your problem solved?

Answer (score 4):

You have `multiple` and `expanded` not set, these options are by default `false`, meaning you are trying to render a `select` element.

By default Symfony doesn't add a `required` attribute to `select` elements when `required` option is set to true, instead it doesn't render an empty `option` in your `select` element.

If you want to have an empty `option` and `required` attribute added to your `select` element you should add a `placeholder` option in your form:

```
$builder
    ->add('fournisseur', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Fournisseur',
        'choice_label' => 'name',
        //'empty_data'  => null,
       'required' => true,  // not needed since it is true by default,
       'placeholder' => 'Choose a fournisseur'
    ))
```

This will render an empty `option` with 'Choose a fournisseur' text inside your `select` element, along with `required` attribute to this `select`.

Comment: A couple of years later, but I have this setup and it doesn't work for me.  Not to crap over the answer, but to report on with my results.

Answer (score 3):

```
$builder
->add('fournisseur', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Fournisseur',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    //'empty_data'  => null,
    'attr'=>[
          'required'=>'required'
            ],
))
```

Comment: This worked in my case but @iiirxs answer didn't. This also work with the 'placeholder' option, meaning that you can do what is stated in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would do the following:

```
$builder
->add('fournisseur', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Fournisseur',
    'choice_label' => 'name',
    //'empty_data'  => null,
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(new NotBlank()),
))
```

Or if the type (ArrivageType) has a 'date_class' (let's say Entity/Arrivage.php), then you can specify validation for it in the file: validation.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Arrivage:
    properties:
      fournisseur:
         - NotBlank: ~
```